# How do you add a black background to text in Python PIL?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm looking to put black backgrounds on text using PIL in Python that automatically adjust to the width and height of the text.

Currently, I have code that constructs the text at equal distances from each other. How would I now put a black background on each line?

```
font_fname = r'user\arial.ttf'
font_size = 50
font = ImageFont.truetype(font_fname, font_size)
text = 'This is a picture of a dolphin having fun'
text_items = wrap(text, 25)
for i in range(4):
    try:
        number = str(i)
        item = text_items[i]
        exec(str("line" + number + ' = ''"""' + item + '"""'))
    except:
        pass
spacing = spacing + 30
par_spacing = 40
for i in range(len(opening_par_items) + 1):
    line_number = str(i)
    try:
        exec("draw.text((130, " + str(spacing) + "), line_" + line_number + ", font=font , fill='rgb(255, 255, 255)')")
        spacing = spacing + par_spacing
    except:
        pass
```

[image: The output would aim to be something like this]

Comment: why on earth do you use `exec()`? stick those lines in a dictionary. then you can access them by index. -- draw black rectangles explicitly. use `ImageDraw.textbbox` to determine the bounds of the text, draw the rectangle, draw the text.